# How to change light colour/intensity on new Blender?

Tags: lighting

Just downloaded Blender 3.6 and am editing a scene. Clicked on the light properties and I can't find how to adjust the light colour/intensity anymore. Where did it go?

[image]

---

[image]
Picture here of scene with lights

Comment: Can you share the scene (only the light)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: ah so weird, i was deleting everything apart from the lights, to upload the blend file, and now i can see the light properties?! weird. it just appeared again! 

not sure what happened but i appreciate you taking the time to get back to me! thanks!

Comment: Ok, glad i could help(?). Out of curiosity: do the light options stay intact when you restore the whole scene?

Comment: yes they do seem to!